# How to convert enum's equivalent to enum in JSON deserialization process in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, json, api, asp.net-core

I have this enumeration:

```
public enum FilterOperator
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Equal = 1,
    GreaterThan = 2,
    LessThan = 3,
    GreaterThanOrEqual = 4,
    LessThanOrEqual = 5,
    NotEqual = 6,
    In = 7,
    NotIn = 8
}
```

And I have this model in my APIs:

```
public class Filter
{
    public string Property { get; set; }

    public FilterOperator Operator { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And I use a JSON string to specify filters in my APIs. For example:

```
GET http://api.example.com/customers/list?filters=[{"property":"age","operator":"lessThan","value":"38"}]
```

And create a custom model binder to read `filters` parameter from HTTP request, and populate a `List<Filter>` for me.

Everything is working perfect. However, for the sake of readability, I prefer to be able to use mathematical symbols in my API calls. In other words I want to be able to use `<` instead of `lessThan`:

```
GET http://api.example.com/customers/list?filters=[{"property":"age","operator":"<","value":"38"}]
```

But this causes error as `<` can not be casted to `FilterOperator` enumeration.

Is there a way to make this case possible?

Comment: Have you tried to encode the `<`? Like `%3C`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [EnumMemberAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute?view=netframework-4.8) . You should write next code for achive what you want:

```
public enum FilterOperator
{
    Unknown = 0,
    [EnumMember(Value = "=")]
    Equal = 1,
    [EnumMember(Value = ">")]
    GreaterThan = 2,
    [EnumMember(Value = "<")]
    LessThan = 3,
    [EnumMember(Value = ">=")]
    GreaterThanOrEqual = 4,
    [EnumMember(Value = "<=")]
    LessThanOrEqual = 5,
    [EnumMember(Value = "!=")]
    NotEqual = 6,
    In = 7,
    NotIn = 8
}
```